# Not able to get error in pubnub javascript callback

Tags: javascript, cordova, push-notification, pubnub

I am following the howto in this blog post: http://www.pubnub.com/blog/sending-android-push-notifications-via-gcm-javascript-using-phonegap/

Up til now I have done the following:

- Created a new project in Google Dev Console
- Turned on Google Cloud Messaging for Android
- Got the sender ID (project number) and a server
  key

Then added push plugin to existing project:

```
$ cordova plugin add https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin.git
```

Then copied PushNotification.js from the plugin to my js lib folder. 
I am loading both this js file and the pubnub cdn with requirejs, which seems to work fine.

I created a module with the scripts from 2.2 in the howto.

```
define(['env-config','datastore/localstore','jquery','push','pubnub'],function (EnvConfig,Store) {

  var pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;   

  function register() {
    pushNotification.register( 
      successHandler, 
      errorHandler, 
      { 'senderID':EnvConfig.push.senderid, 'ecb':'onNotificationGCM'} 
    );
  } 

  function successHandler(result) { 
    console.log('Success: '+ result); 
  }

  function errorHandler(error) { 
    //** The following line throws: 
    //** java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    console.log('Error:' + error);
  }

  function onNotificationGCM(e) { 
    switch(e.event){ 
      case 'registered': 
        console.log("Device registered with id "+e.regid);
        Store.set("pushid"+e.regid);
        /*if (e.regid.length > 0) { 
          deviceRegistered(e.regid); 
        } */
        break;   
      case 'message': 
        if (e.foreground){ 
          //What needs to be done when app is in the foreground 
          //while receiving a notification 
          console.log('A notification has been received'); 
        } 
        break;   
      case 'error': 
        console.log('Error: ' + e.msg); 
        break;   
      default: console.log('An unknown event was received'); 
      break; 
    } 
  } 

  var module = {
    init: function() {
      register();
    }
  };

  return module;
});
```

When device is ready, I call the init function of this module.

At the moment register() fails and executes the errorHandler callback. But console.log fails with: **java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.String**. Therefore I have no idea what to do next...

Any pointers is much appreciated.

Samsung Galaxy S5
Android 4.4.2
Chrome 30.0 (in webview)
Cordova 3.6.3-0.2.13

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, I think I know what's going on-
Your sender ID has to be in string! You are probably using it as a number.

BTW, thanks for trying out the tutorial I wrote :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot... it works now :-) ... by the way, I also have to attach onNotificationGCM callback to the window object as described in this issue: https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin/issues/313